# WPF Popup window closes but is not updating MainWindow UserControl datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I have an application that has MainWindow with multiple UserControls. In one of the UserControls, there is a Datagrid. Inside that Datagrid, the user can select a row to make changes. When a row is selected a new window shows allowing the user to make changes and save data to a local SQLite database. Then when the user closes and saves the data from the popup Window, I expect the UserControl in the MainWindow to update the DataGrid.

When the popup window is closed, all the data is updated in the SQLite table, but the Datagrid is not refreshed. When I debug I can see that all the methods are called to retrieve the data and the OnPropertyChanged is called, but the datagrid does not show any of the changes.

My question is, how can I update UserControl in the MainWindow when I close a popup window?

**MainWindow UserControl DataGrid**

```
            <DataGrid Name="datagrid"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PendingResults, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  Height="450"
                  Margin="5"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue"
                  CanUserSortColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"
                                    Binding="{Binding ID}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Client"
                                    Binding="{Binding Client}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                    Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header=Type"
                                    Binding="{Binding TestType}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.LoadCommand}">Finish</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}">Delete</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

MainWindow UserControl ViewModel

```
    internal class PendingTestsViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public List<SavedTestResults> _pendingResults;
        public SavedTestResults _selectedRow { get; set; }

        public List<SavedTestResults> PendingResults
        {
            get { return _pendingResults; }
            set { _pendingResults = value; OnPropertyChanged("PendingResults"); }
        }


        public SavedTestResults SelectedRow
        {
            get { return _selectedRow; }
            set { _selectedRow = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

    public RelayCommand LoadMeterCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand RefreshPendingListCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand DeleteMeterCommand { get; set; }

    public PendingTestsViewModel()
    {
        LoadMeterCommand = new RelayCommand(o => TestSelectedMeter());
        DeleteMeterCommand = new RelayCommand(o => DeletePendingTest());
        RefreshPendingListCommand = new RelayCommand(o => PendingSearchResults());

        PendingSearchResults();
    }

    private void PendingSearchResults()
    {

        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("data source=Database.sqlite"))
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(con))
            {
                StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

                query.Append(@"Query Test is here");

                com.CommandText = query.ToString();
                con.Open();

                try
                {
                    List<SavedTestResults> Results = new List<SavedTestResults>();

                    SQLiteDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        SavedResults results = new SavedResults();
                          //results are added here

                        Results.Add(results);
                    }

                    PendingResults = Results; //Update ObservableCollection
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

ObservableObject Class

```
internal class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

This is how I am calling the UserControl in the MainWindow from my PopupWindow. When the popup window is closed I call this method.

```
public void RefreshPending()
{

    PendingTests pendingTests = new PendingTests();

}
```

Comment: From first look, it looks like your editor window is retrieving test from db NOT the datagrid. So when the window closes you either reload the tests in datagrid from database or you pass the amended entity back to datagrid. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That is correct. My editor window calls the db to get the data. When saved it updates the db and then the MainWindow UserControl is called. The Usercontrol then calls the PendingSearchResult() method in the ViewModel to get the new data. That call then assigns the new data PendingResults. PendingResults is what is loaded into the DataGrid. That is where I am having issues. The new PendingResults is not loaded into the DataGrid.

Comment: And you can confirm that your changes are reflected in the database? Cause it looks to me like you have an issue with data retrieval rather than WPF.

Comment: @GoForIt: How and when is the `RefreshPendingListCommand` executed? And how and where are you opening the popup window?

Comment: @XAMlMAX I can confirm the data is saved to the DB. When the popup window closes, I can go to another UserControl in the MainWindow and then go back to the UserControl that contains by DataGrid and the data will load with my updates.

Comment: @mm8 That is linked to a button in my UserControl. I am using that as a way to update the DataGrid since when I close the popup window that data won't update. Basically, when I close the popup window, I can go and press that button and it will update the DataGrid. That has been my workaround until I can figure out why my DataGrid is not updated on the closing of my popup window.

Comment: Just a note: in your code it should be  `PendingResults = Results` not `results`. I am sure it's just a typo.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Sorry about that. That was a typo. I have updated the question to show Results.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I have updated how I am calling the MainWindow UserControl once the popup window is closed. I have added the Method to the above question.

Comment: *"all the methods are called to retrieve the data and the OnPropertyChanged is called, but the datagrid does not show any of the changes."* - It looks like you have two different instances of PendingTestsViewModel: you bind to one while operate on the other. You should post a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Otherwise there is nothing we can review. Your posted code lacks all its context. It's not helpful.

Comment: `con.Close();` is redundant because `con` is instantiated in a using declaration. `OnPropertyChanged("PendingResults")"` should be called without an argument (or at least using `nameof`)  to avoid typos (and enable compiler support). `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is the default value and can be omitted to compact the Binding expression.

Comment: And why do you create a new instance of the `PendingTests` control? Didn't you meant to update the existing control? Again. it looks like you messed up the DataContext. Maybe you should check it.

Comment: I think BionicCode is on to something here. I would narrow your testing sample to 1 result and then compare results when you test. Also use memory diagnostic tool in VS and look for more than 1 instance of  that item you're checking. There is a line of code somewhere that is messing this up, just 1.